# creating a new column in ms access based on a name category

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a table in Access that looks something similar to this:

| NAME | CITY|

I want to create a new column for each city and display the names living in it. At the moment I have 3 cities : Chicago, New York and Texas. So it should look something like this:

| Chicago residents | New York residents | Texas residents |

and the name of each resident under those fields.

I know this is possible to create by having multiple queries and each query uses 'contains' to create a new field - but I don't want to have multiple queries. I want to only have one query (for speed purposes). Is this possible at all? I've tried using the expression builder but I can't seem to find any possible solutions.

Comment: Where is city named Texas?

Comment: @June7: [Texas City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_City,_Texas).

Comment: @Gustav, of course - I should have known!

Answer (score 0):

Transpose data via CROSSTAB query. A CROSSTAB requires 3 fields. Assuming your table has only the two fields shown or other fields are not appropriate, third field can be calculated.

```
TRANSFORM First([Name]) AS FirstOfName
SELECT DCount("*","Table","City='" & [City] & "' AND [Name]<'" & [Name] & "'") + 1 AS Seq
FROM Table
GROUP BY DCount("*","Table","City='" & [City] & "' AND [Name]<'" & [Name] & "'") + 1
PIVOT City;
```